# Prioritizing A/B tests by using the prior data

Tags: bayesian, estimation, prior, ab-test

Let's say that I am an active user of the Tinder app and in addition to the standard features, I've got access to the A/B testing of my primary picture (the one that appears first when users stumble on my profile).
My objective is maximizing the number of "swipe right" events, so I try various pictures, but I test them first to make sure that they wouldn't harm the "swipe right rate". I am using [Bayesian approach](http://developers.lyst.com/2014/05/10/bayesian-ab-testing/) to assess the test pictures' performance as soon as possible. I'm preserving the history of my test results which looks like:
[image]

So far so good. But I can only run the single test at a time, let's say this is the limitation of this hypothetical Tinder Testing feature. At the same time I have a lot of pictures I would like to try, so I need to somehow prioritize them. Here is the idea :

- Compare each picture with the basiline one and detect what areas have been changed. For example in one of the new pictures I have a new haircut, so "hairs" have changed, another one features my new car, so "environment" has changed and so on.
- For each area select the tests results from the history and build the beta-distribution of the "swipe right rate" of those tests.
- Compare the calculated beta distributions by using one of the available methods, let's say compare the graphs to roughly estimate which area can provide better results.
- Arrange the "tests backlog" accordingly.

I do not have the strong math/stat background, so I understand that that idea might be pretty silly, but I would like to know what community thinks about that. In general what methods could be used to prioritize the a/b tests based on the prior data?

Comment: Not quite directly related to your questions but you might take a lok at response surface methodology; while it's not typically used for binary responses, some of the ideas would perhaps be relevant to you.